# HTTP Status 500 Error Tomcat 7.0.23 After CF 10 Update 14

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion

I recently applied the CF 10 update 14 afterwards I received this error when trying to access the admin panel.

```
HTTP Status 500
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:129)
    coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    coldfusion.CfmServlet.init(CfmServlet.java:97)
    coldfusion.bootstrap.ClassloaderHelper.initServletClass(ClassloaderHelper.java:121)
    coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.init(BootstrapServlet.java:59)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
    org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:204)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to be because a hotfix was not installed correctly. I did a manual uninstall from the command prompt:

```
java -jar {cf_install_home}/{instance_home}/hf_updates/hf-10-00014/uninstall /uninstaller.jar
```

checked the log file and found a access error to the hf_updates folder. Applied read/write properties to the folder and re-installed CF 10 Update 14. All works now.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is still applicable for CF 10 Update 19.  Updated failed because security hardening procedures restricted access to the OS and CF instance root and that user didn't have access to the hf_updates/* folder.  Once granted the installation through the cf admin panel worked flawless.

Just update the uninstall command as follows:

```
java -jar {cf_install_home}/{instance_home}/hf_updates/hf-10-00019/uninstall /uninstaller.jar
```